# как тоже самое вывести с помощью двумерного массива?

Tags: c#

код выводит заполненный круг, не получается вывести то же самое используя двумерный массив. В Преобразованиях типов не могу разобраться

```
namespace ConsoleApp00
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Random rd = new Random();

            double r;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter radius of circle : ");
                if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out r) || r <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid radius, try again");
                }
            }
            while (r <= 0);

            Console.WriteLine();
            bool fill = false;
            string input;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Do you want to fill the circle  y/n : ");
                input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (input != "y" && input != "n")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid reply, try again");
                }
                else if (input == "y")
                {
                    fill = true;
                }
            }
            while (input != "y" && input != "n");

            Console.WriteLine();

            double r_in = r - 0.4;
            double r_out = r + 0.4;

            for (double y = r; y >= -r; --y)
            {




                for (double x = -r; x < r_out; x += 0.5)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)rd.Next(16);
                    double value = x * x + y * y;
                    if (value >= r_in * r_in && value <= r_out * r_out)
                    {

                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    else if (fill && value < r_in * r_in && value < r_out * r_out)
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно для чего именно нужно применить двумерный массив. В любом случае переписывание кода — слишком широкая задача для одного вопроса на Stack Overflow, т.к. для этого потребуется учесть все моменты. Возможно лучше будет показать Вашу попытку и задать вопрос по конкретной проблеме.

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте рассуждать:

- для круга радиусом `r` нужен массив размером `(2*r+1)x(2*r+1)`
- cчетчики циклов x и y подозрительно похожи на координаты, так что можно сделать их целыми и использовать единичный шаг
- чтобы индексы массива были неотрицательными - можно добавить к координатам r и использовать их как индексы
- там, где в коде выводится точка, в соответствующий элемент массив заносить единицу, а где пробел - ноль

Посильно реализовать?

Comment: [режим зануды] В шарпе/дотнете можно создавать массивы с отрицательными (начинающимися не с нуля) индексами. [/режим зануды] Однако, лучше так не делать. А ваш способ правильный.

Comment: Да, про такую экзотику (если речь о CreateInstance c lowerbound, а не об индексаторах) я не вспомнил

Comment: для круга радиусом 2*r нужен массив размером (**4***r+1)x(**4***r+1)

Comment: @Igor Угу, исправил радиус на r